Entity Framework Core C# recursive load of the parent child relationship lazy loading
I have a table in my database with a parentID column referencing the same table's ID key column. Each entry in that table can have a parent - record from the same table and list of children - also from the same table.
Is there any way to lazy load all child / parent items from that table using Entity Framework Core, without having circular reference issues and without using Entity Framework Core's native functions:
 .Include(...)
    .ThenInclude(...)

I couldn't find a way to do that simply and nicely.

Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the "circular reference issues" you have. Also add a [mcve] of the source code you have, the table structure you have in the database and the entity classes you have (including any model information you have).

To work with the adjacency list, you must use a recursive CTE. The usual Entity Framework does not know how to do this. As far as I know, the only ORM that can use CTE is linq2db. However you can try the linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore library.

Consider using the HierarchyId. Or use pure SQL.

@AlexanderPetrov HierarchyId only works for a small subset of graphs (specifically, strict hiearchies) whereas the way that the OP described their schema suggests they might have reference-cycles and/or need to reparent arbitrary elements - that's not something you can do with HierarchyId.
